# Excel 2013 FIFO Report based on Log

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Lately i've been building an asset tracker/inventory on excel. It's pretty elaborate and has been working well with over 20 people using the original file in Read Only, and then querying outside databases. They're able to make edits, process sales, builds, and other types of movements for each product On the back end, there's a log created of each movement a user makes. I use this log to calculate things such as average price, cost, overall sales tracking by date, as well as other things.

Recently the boss asked me to start calculating our cost and profit based on FIFO. I have been doing my research and have been leaning towards a VBA approach considering my companies workstations have more cores then ghz. After numerous google results and trying to adapt the approach to my logs, i've come up unsuccessful. The problem is that not to many of the sites explain how to adapt the macros/formulas to another sheet that may not fit the same criteria as the example given.

The question is: Can anyone help me adapt my log to a FIFO report? I really would like to learn this, so please explain a little with any answers given.

Here's an example of my log. Name is in Col. A

```
        Name    Time    SKU Quantity    QTY Change  Cost    Price   Desc    Type    Order #
    Loops   7/12/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  0   100 4           Update  Update Order 1
    Loops   7/13/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  100 -100        17      Wholesale   Wholesale Order 1
    Loops   7/14/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  0   100 4           Update  Update Order 2
    Loops   7/15/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  100 -1      17      Sale    Sale Order 1
    Loops   7/16/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  99  10  5.5         Update  Update Order 3
    Loops   7/17/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  109 -5      19.99       Sale    Sale Order 2
    Loops   7/18/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  104 -5      22      Build Item  Build Item Order 1
    Loops   7/19/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  99  -1      19.99       Sale    Sale Order 3
    Loops   7/20/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  98  -4      0       Scrap   Scrap Order 1
    Loops   7/21/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  94  -2      9       Build Item  Build Item Order 2
    Loops   7/22/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  92  -1      19.99       Sale    Sale Order 4
    Loops   7/23/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  91  -1      22      Build Item  Build Item Order 3
    Loops   7/24/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  90  -20     17      Wholesale   Wholesale Order 2
    Loops   7/25/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  70  20  5.5         Update  Update Order 4
    Loops   7/26/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  90  -9      19.49       Sale    Sale Order 5
    Loops   7/27/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  81  3   2           Update  Update Order 5
    Loops   7/28/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  84  100 4           Update  Update Order 6
    Loops   7/29/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  184 -50     16      Wholesale   Wholesale Order 3
    Loops   7/30/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  134 -2      0       Scrap   Scrap Order 2
    Loops   7/31/17 12:00 AM    Test 1  132 -1      22      Build Item  Build Item Order 4
    Loops   8/1/17 12:00 AM Test 1  131 -5      18.99       Sale    Sale Order 6
    Loops   8/2/17 12:00 AM Test 1  126 -1      0       Replacement Replacement Order 1
    Loops   8/3/17 12:00 AM Test 1  125 -40     16      Wholesale   Wholesale Order 4
    Loops   8/4/17 12:00 AM Test 1  85  10  5           Update  Update Order 7
    Loops   8/5/17 12:00 AM Test 1  95  -20     16      Wholesale   Wholesale Order 5
    Loops   8/6/17 12:00 AM Test 1  75  20  4.5         Update  Update Order 8
    Loops   8/7/17 12:00 AM Test 1  95  -1      18.99       Sale    Sale Order 7
    Loops   8/8/17 12:00 AM Test 1  94  -2      0       Scrap   Scrap Order 3
    Loops   8/9/17 12:00 AM Test 1  92  -1      0       Scrap   Scrap Order 4
    Loops   8/10/17 10:02 AM    Test 1  91  60  4.25    18.99       Update  Update Order 9
```

(Not sure if i put the snippet in correctly or not)

****EDIT: I need to calculate cost and prices based upon FIFO and LIFO. Theoretically i would be taking the current quantity and subtracting it from the most recent incoming order, and weight that cost along with each order my remaining product came in on. 
If Product A has a current quantity of 10, i need to know what the average cost that specific 10 items is. I can do this on a granular level, but im running this report for 2k individual products with around 100k items in total. My excel based inventory runs about 600 transactions per day, each logged with quantity change, cost, and price, incoming/outgoing order names, etc. So i have the data all there, just no way to query it to my needs.**
 **

Thank you. Loops

Comment: What exactly do you need? A report of what items got sold when? A P&L Report? What does your theoretical output look like, if we know that, we can help you get there.

Comment: Ok, im back at it. Had to build some other items. I added some stuff to the OP